# working with xbrl in .net

Tags: .net, xbrl

I want to create a xbrl report with .net, please let me know how to use it.

Comment: Any suggestion, from where I can start learning it.

Comment: why Vote down for this question ??  +1 from my side

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [Gepsio: XBRL Document Object Model for .NET](http://gepsio.codeplex.com/) to load XBRL documents.

Checkout the [Gepsio Documentation](http://gepsio.codeplex.com/documentation) for a basic example to implement it.

See [Rivet Software Dragon View XBRL Viewer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rivetdragonview/) to view XBRL taxonomies.

Unfortunately, XBRL's momentum on .NET platforms is very slow so documentation on how to implement it will be hard/impossible to come by.

Answer (score 7):

Saying you want to create an XBRL report with .Net is a little like saying you would like to write a novel with the Cyrillic alphabet and asking how to do so.

There are APIs and DOMs for working with XBRL with .Net (e.g., Google the terms "gepsio and XBRL" or "Hitachi Systems XiRUTE .NET", which as the name suggests supports Microsoft .NET framework.)

Most of the available APIs are for Java.

The SEC provides source code for XBRL viewers (http://www.sec.gov/spotlight/xbrl/renderingenginelicense.htm) from which you might learn. Where else can you learn XBRL? The XBRL ORG web site has the Specification(s), conformance suites, samples.

Answer (score 0):

As of beginning of 2020, xbrl.org has this list of tools available for working with xbrl:
https://www.xbrl.org/the-standard/how/tools-and-services/